# When naming objects in an OOP language, what is the difference between "map" and "transform"?

Tags: oop, dictionary, transformation, naming, conventions

To me, naming is a critical concept in Software Engineering. For that reason, I'm a huge fan of Design Patterns because it gives me (what I think are) appropriate names for commonly found patterns/objects.

When creating objects whose purpose it is to convert one object to another, and vice versa, I usually use the name "map":

```
IDictionary<long, User> _userIdMap = new // ...

public class UserMapper
{
    UserModel ToModel(UserViewModelModel viewModelModel) { ... }
    UserViewModelModel ToViewModelModel(UserModel model) { ... }
}
```

However recently I joined a project where objects of this nature are called Transformers and I understand why they could also be called this.

It is my understanding that the term "map" is appropriate when there is a clear bidirectional one-to-one relationship: ObjectA can be "mapped" to ObjectB if ObjectB can be "mapped" to ObjectA. If the relationship is one-way then (my understanding is) that it's not truly a "map" in classic Computer Science terms.

Is there a standard, traditional distinction between mappers, transformers, converters, or other (not already mentioned here) names for objects that change one object into another, and if so, what delineations or rules of thumb should be considered when naming these objects?

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. Maybe you want to take a look at category theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In computer science, a "Map" is used to associate a known value/entity to another known value/entity e.g as in your question, ObjectA can be mapped to ObjectB.

A "Transform" is used to convert/transform any acceptable value into another using a function e.g. a "transform" to calculate x^2; x could be any value.

Hence as a "rule of thumb" a map should be used if a *finite* set of objects/values have a clear relationship, whereas a transform should be used if dealing with a *non-finite* set of values/entities where a value should be calculated using a function.

Comment: Or equivalently, a map is *looked up* whereas a transformation is *performed*.

Comment: @PaulHicks Yes, when I say "finite set of objects/values have a clear relationship" I imply that a map is "looked up". +1 though for clearly stating "looked up" and "performed" :)

Comment: Note that this has very little to do with OOP or design patterns: it's customary terminology in all of CS. (But not in math where a map may well be infinite.)

Comment: Do any of you have thoughts on "Convert" versus Transform? I like the term better, but I'm also curious if random programmers (i.e. you guys) have a preconceived notion for that canonical term than I.

Comment: @MartinBliss as I have a scientific background, I prefer to use the term "transform" as this is what it is usually called in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)).

Comment: @Fresh From a Math perspective, given my example of an IDictionary<long, User> would you agree that the contract does not provide enough implementation details to determine whether it's a map or just a transformer? For example, Dictionary<long, User> (a concrete type that implements the interface) has a unique constraint on T1, but NOT T2, so it's technically just a transformer, but a different type could implement the contract which places a constraint on both T1 and T2, and then it could be a map. Thoughts?

Comment: A dictionary (as you know) represents a collection of key value pairs (i.e. it maps keys to values); it is not a transformer, it is inherently a map. If you had a method like "long GetUserId(User)" in your contract, where the user ID could be calculated purely from the User class, then GetUserId would be deemed a transformer, as it would transform the User into a userID.